# How to validate date yymmdd with leap year support

Tags: html, forms, date, leap-year

I need to validate a text input for the format yymmdd with a regular expression.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="12" name="ic_no" 
pattern="(((0[048]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])0229)|[0-9]{2}(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])
|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31)))[0-9]{6}" required>
```

ic_no means Identification Card Number. The first 6 digits are yymmdd, next 6 digits are random digits. For example: 730228072435.

When I input a date like 730229, it shows an error to count the age. Because it is a leap year, it should be 730228 to count the age.

How to validate yymmdd format with leap year support? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some leap year regex out there, but they are pretty complicated.
It would be much more readable using JavaScript. Is that an option for you?

Comment: nope, I have to use forms input. Is it  okay?

Comment: So the `pattern` you are currently using is not working?

Comment: it only can input the date until the 29th. The 30th and 31th cannot be input. For example, 000229 okay, bur 000430, 000531 cannot.

Comment: Is the pattern in my answer solving your issue? If not, can you try to clarify your issue?

Comment: no, this pattern solves the 28th, 29th, 30th, 31th problem for February. But, it cannot input 1st until 09th.

Comment: Should 73021 match? Can you send examples of non matching dates using my pattern?

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should work:

`((0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])0229|\d\d((0[13578]|1[02])([0-2]\d|3[01])|(0[469]|11)([0-2]\d|30)|02([01]\d|2[0-8])))\d{6}`